# Why am I getting an "undefined" when I try to show a value from object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Why am I getting an error undefined?

```
user.findAll({
     where: { email: req.body.email },
     raw: true
})
.then(function (resUser) {
     console.log(resUser.name)
})
```

I'm trying to show the name:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'user',
    email: 'user@outlook.com',
    createdAt: 2020-08-27T22:52:39.059Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-09-01T21:33:27.458Z,
  }
]
```

Thanks

Comment: It's an array with all matching records, it's not a record itself (note the `[ ]` in your output). Maybe you want `findOne` instead of `findAll`?

Comment: console.log(resUser[0].name (ti's an array which is to be expected from a findAll method)

Comment: @user3791775 yes but then it's pretty useless to first fetch all matching records just to then access only the first one, don't you think?

Comment: @CherryDT But it is the reason why resUser.name is undefined

Answer (score 2):

You use `findAll` that returns an array of found objects so either you should get `resUser[0]` OR if you're sure you always get one record only then you can use `findOne` and you'll get an object or `null` if no record was found.